# AngularJS submit form inside ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I have a form inside an `ng-if` inside a controller with an `ng-include`, which doesn't submit...

I know `ng-if` and `ng-include` creates their own scopes, but I thought you could access controller methods..

**index.html**

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div data-ng-include="form.html" data-ng-if="loadForm"></div>
</div>
```

**form.html**

```
<form action="" data-ng-submit="submit($event)">
    <input type="text" name="foo" data-ng-model="foo">
    <input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>
```

**ctrl.js**

```
'use strict';
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $element, $http, $log) {
        $scope.loadForm = true;

        $scope.submit = function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log("hello");
        };
    }
);
```

When I click on submit, nothing is logged into console, also `e.preventDefault();` not firing...

I know the issue is scope hierarchy... I can't do `data-ng-submit="$parent.submit($event)"` because the form will be used elsewhere and form code needs to be reusable.

Comment: try `myCtrl as formCtrl` and `formCtrl.submit`

Comment: It doesn't work neither...

Comment: Just to make sure it's scoping related and not an event handling issue: What happens when you call a controller function from your submit input via ng-click instead?

Comment: if I use it with `as formCtrl` nothing hapens, if I just do `data-ng-click="submit($event)"` then the method is fired correctly

Comment: Weird. That kinda speaks against the scope hierarchy hypothesis

Comment: I would recommend to create a directive instead of using ng-include you can pass the submit function to the directive and use it.

Comment: I thought about that, but I need to create a new file and we have a lot right now... And it is only to render an html inside a div through API url... I will research a little more, just in case ng-submit works in other way than scopes... dunno

Comment: Found the problem... So stupid from my side.... My button was actually an anchor tag, not an input nor a button... That's why my form wasn't firing controller method, because it just didn't submit. It works now... I feel so stupid... I hate mondays :P

Comment: @robert, look here- http://jsfiddle.net/xyeh1rkt/6/

Answer (score 0):

@Robert, you can use ng-show instead of using ng-if.
Because ng-if create/destroy the new DOM tree  based on expression evaluation true/false respectively.

Comment: The expression `loadForm` evaluated to `true`. So it's not a `ng-if` problem either.

Comment: @SudhirOjha, you are right. I try to run the above problem and that's working see here- jsfiddle.net/xyeh1rkt/6